# How to do an IN on a subquery with a CSV?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following varchar value '1,2,4,5, ...' in a table column.
Basically, they're just codes in CSV format. I know it's a bad design, but that's what I have to deal with unfortunately.

Now I want to create a subquery to find descriptions that correspond to all codes.
How do I do that?

I've tried a subquery like

```
SELECT description FROM table WHERE table.CODE IN tablewithcsv.csvcolumn
```

But to no avail. 
Normal IN's expect values like `('1', '2', '3')`, but I suspect my value gets passed as `'1,2,3'`. Do I have to do some replacing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search in a string, you can use:

```
SELECT description FROM `table`
INNER JOIN `tablewithcsv` ON `tablewithcsv`.csvcolumn LIKE '%' + `table`.CODE + '%'
```

This will work if the integers are only on character long, but will return false positives on more than one char. If you have more than one char, you can change it as such:

```
SELECT description FROM `table`
INNER JOIN `tablewithcsv` ON `tablewithcsv`.csvcolumn = `table`.CODE
  OR `tablewithcsv`.csvcolumn LIKE `table`.CODE + ',%'
  OR `tablewithcsv`.csvcolumn LIKE '%,' + `table`.CODE
  OR `tablewithcsv`.csvcolumn LIKE '%,' + `table`.CODE + ',%'
```

This could also be done more elegantly using regular expressions

Comment: @Davio - And also matches `12,41`

Comment: You're right, Martin, of course, but luckily for me the "integers" are all fixed length "keys".